# chefspec failed with "ffi-libarchive could not be loaded"

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

I'm new to chef. Recently, I'm studying how to use chefspec to test recipe. But I always failed with "ffi-libarchive could not be loaded" error. Here's my steps.

1. I use gem to install chefspec --
   gem install 'chefspec'
   It's successfully installed.
2. Then I write a test cookbook -- sample, with a recipe default.rb --

   package 'apache2'
   service 'apache2' do
   action [:enable, :start]
   end

   file '/srv/www/htdocs/index.html' do
   content '

   ## Welcome! You have successfully configured your chef node.

   '
   end
3. Then in c:\work\chef-repo\cookbooks\sample\spec, I create default_spec.rb --

   require 'chefspec'

   describe 'index html' do
   let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new(platform: 'suse', version: '12.4').converge(described_recipe) }

   ```
   it 'deletes a file with an explicit action' do
     expect(chef_run).to create_file_with_content('/www/srv/index.html','Welcome! You have successfully configured your chef node.')
     expect(chef_run).to_not delete_file('/tmp/e.log')
   end
   ```

   end
4. Then I tried rspec , but it failed --

   C:\Work\chef-repo>rspec cookbooks\sample\spec\default_spec.rb
   ffi-libarchive could not be loaded, libarchive is probably not installed on system, archive_file will not be available
   F

   Failures:

   1. index html deletes a file with an explicit action......
5. So I installed ffi-libarchive again, but the rspec still failed --

   C:\Work\chef-repo>gem install 'ffi-libarchive'
   Successfully installed ffi-libarchive-1.1.3
   Parsing documentation for ffi-libarchive-1.1.3
   Done installing documentation for ffi-libarchive after 3 seconds
   1 gem installed

   C:\Work\chef-repo>rspec cookbooks\sample\spec\default_spec.rb
   ffi-libarchive could not be loaded, libarchive is probably not installed on system, archive_file will not be available

   Please kind help. Thanks in advance for any idea.